# How to mute microphone in javascript

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

So I am creating a video calling web app and I want to put mic on/off, video on/off functions in there.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
            }).then(stream => {
            const video= document.getElementById("my-video");
            video.srcObject = stream
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
                video.play()
             })
```

It looks like this. Now I want to create a toggle function for my camera and micrphone. How do I do it

Comment: None of the already available ["how to mute microphone"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+mute+microphone+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=ffab&ia=web) questions work for you?

Answer (score 5):

You receive a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) using `getUserMedia()`. Stream consists of several tracks both video and audio.

`videoMediaStream.getAudioTracks()` will give you list of audio tracks.

`videoMediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false` will mute your [mic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled#usage_notes).

This is what the docs mention regarding `enabled` property:

> If the MediaStreamTrack represents the video input from a camera, disabling the track by setting enabled to false also updates device activity indicators to show that the camera is not currently recording or streaming. For example, the green "in use" light next to the camera in iMac and MacBook computers turns off while the track is muted in this way.

You can follow something similar for your camera using `getVideoTracks()`.