# How can I mute the microphone using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I'm developing a telephone with Sveltekit, and using Janus library to do the calls. I'm trying to mute the call using JavaScript, catching the audio track and trying to change its state like the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled) said.

No matter what, I can't change the state of `enabled` of the stream track, it stays `true` and the microphone keeps working.

The code I implemented is basically this

```
  function toggleMic(){
    isMuted = !isMuted;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false})
    .then((stream) => {
      const tracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
      tracks.forEach(track => {
        console.log(track.enabled)
        track.enabled = !track.enabled
        console.log(track.enabled)
      });
    })
  }
```

On the console.log when the function is called, it displays `true` and `false` in sequence, but if I call the function again, the state of `enabled` should be `false`, but it's true again. It's like the last call had no effect on the track.

This other post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68161040/how-to-mute-microphone-in-javascript) suggested the change of the `enabled` property of the track, and I'm doing this on the `track.enabled = !track.enabled` to every function call, toggling between mute and unmute.

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` should only be called once.

In your case, each time you call it, it is opening a new MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack and doing away with the old ones, making it difficult to troubleshoot if your track muting is working as you'd like.

Additionally, although many browsers handle calling `getUserMedia` multiple times gracefully, this is not a guarantee. Some user browsers may fail on subsequent calls.

I recommend moving `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` outside of `toggleMic` and have `toggleMic` act on a stream passed into it.

Something like:

```js
// when the page first loads, ask user for mic permission and get stream if allowed
// should also add any error handling here for all the failure cases like user denies permission, no devices available, etc.
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});

// use the global mediaStream variable to act on the same stream you first instantiated
const toggleMic = () => {
    mediaStream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track => {
        track.enabled = !track.enabled
    });
};
```